# Input Autocomplete or New in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I have a simple doubt. I'm working on ruby on rails 5, and I have a relation where the parent is 'category' and the child is 'phrase'. My user can create phrases but I don't want a separate form to create categories, which is just an id and a name. I want in the form for phrases an input where the user can type a category and an autocomplete will pop up with the avaliable options, but if he wants a new one, he simply types it and it will create a new one when he saves the form.

I've seen something similar with jquery-ui autocomplete but I couldn't make it work properly because it requires a predefined list inside the javascript. thank you.

Comment: the ruby part is just about create a form_for category with nested attributes for phrase. the jquery part you can solve with the link that @muistooshort gave you above or you can use [link](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I did a mix of both answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a similar solution is to  use `datalist` and `option` tags for your input. like :

```
   <%= form_for @phrase do |phrase_form| %>
     <%= f.text_field :name >
        #=> other fields for phrase ........

        <%= fields_for :category do |category_builder| %>
        <%= category_builder.text_field :name, :list => "categories_list" %>
         <datalist id = "categories_list" >
           <% Category.all.each do |c| do %>
           <option value = "<%=c.name%>"  ></option>
           <% end %>    
         </datalist>
        <% end %>    
        <% end %>
```

then you add  `accept_nested_attributes_for :category`  in `phrase.rb` model file

once you type in text field you will get a list of available options for categories

other solution is to define a new methods for phrase `category_name` and `category_name=(name)`

```
def category_name=(name) 
   self.category = Category.find_or_create_by(:name => name)
end
```

then  `<%= f.text_field :category_name, :list => "categories_list %>"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose which list should be rendering you can make something the same as:

```
<div id="div-breed" class="col-lg-5 input-group-prepend" style="display: none" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Campo Raça é obrigatório">
  <span>Raça (*)</span>
  <%= f.text_field :breed, list: "pet-breed", class: "form-control mt-2" %>

  <datalist id="pet-breed">
    <% breed_canina.each do |canineBreed| %>
      <option value="<%= canineBreed.name %>"></option>
    <% end %>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

And choose which breed need be rendering with Jquery:

```
// #pet_kind can be "Canina" or "Felina"

$('#pet_kind').change(() => {
  $('#div-breed').css("display", "none");

  if ($('#pet_kind').val() === 'Canina') {
    $("#pet-breed").html(
      `<% breed_canina.each do |canineBreed| %>
        <option value="<%= canineBreed.name %>"></option>
      <% end %>`
    );

    $('#div-breed').css("display", "block");
  } else if ($('#pet_kind').val() === 'Felina') {
    $("#pet-breed").html(`
      <% breed_felina.each do |felineBreed| %>
        <option value=\"<%= felineBreed.name %>\"></option>
      <% end %>
     `);

    $('#div-breed').css("display", "block");

  }
});
```